# mdt 2013 how to deploy single os for multiple model pc at once

Tags: mdt, wds

We have multiple model PCs, we have setup MDT 2013+WDS server, for NewComputer or Refresh (reintall) scenario we uses MDT only new PCs all are same model so had no issues so far, for reinstall scenario at once just 1 or 2 PCs deploy.
But now trying to reinstall 4 different model PCs one OS that is Windows 7 x64 Bit for 1. Intel H61-MS 2.ASUS M5A78 3.Mercury PIH81 4.Gigabyte

I have imported all the 4 model PCs into my Deployment Tools-->Out of Box Drivers location, have imported the OS,Application everything, i don't know how to deploy all at once, such that MDT distribute Drivers base on %MODEL% one more draw back is few of the PCs when i check model number using the following cmd  "wmic computersystem get model" throws error "To Be Filled By O.E.M"
Can anyone please suggest me how to perform Same OS Deployment for different model and make.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I build the current MDT environment for the company that I work for and they have over 30 different models of machines by using this method of driver delivery you should be able to deploy multiple types of models at the same time. This method works for both windows 7 and windows 10.

http://techgenix.com/Deploying-Windows-7-Part26/

Comment: @ARdoriguez, thanks for your valuable answer, i followed the same option, but here in my case we still have few old model PCs as mentioned above i'm receiving error on wmic computersystem get model cmd...I doubt if my deployment will finish successfully by obtaining right drivers?? I have created Selection Profile-->Under it imported all the 4 pcs driver..alike suggested under TS-->General-->Set Task Sequence Variable-->Created Windows7x64\%make%\%model% because of non receipt of make model error only i'm suffering...